# ssh and git setup

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git

I am attempting to setup a private git server on my local network and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. I can't seem to get ssh authentication via private key working for the git user.

I have run `ssh-keygen` on the client to create an rsa pub/private key. I have created the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server. I have copied the contents of `id_rsa.pub` over to the `authorized_keys` file on the server, by using `scp` to transfer the file to the server and then `cat id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server to ensure there were no copy errors. I have restarted the ssh daemon.

On the client, the `~/.ssh` folder has permissions 700, and the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file has permissions 600. On the server, the `~/.ssh` folder has permissions 700, and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file has permissions 600.

My server's ssh config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the following uncommented lines

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match User git
        PasswordAuthentication no
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/` folder is empty. The server is running `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. The server's ssh version is `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

Upon attempting to `ssh git@192.168.0.101` I am greeted with the following
`Permission denied (publickey).`

What am I missing? I've looked at guides. I've made sure I am copying the key over accurately. I am honestly stumped because I have inserted public keys into the `authorized_keys` file before on a server with ssh already setup, and it's worked. If I set the sshd config to allow `PasswordAuthentication` then I can login as the git user fine with the password I have set on it. I do not understand why the public private key auth is not working.

Output of `ssh git@192.168.0.101 -vvv`
https://pastebin.com/raw/nJwskYhU

Comment: According to the pastebin, your client is offering id_rsa to the server, and the server isn't accepting it. Try checking the syslogs on the server to see if the sshd process is logging the reason why it's not accepting the key. Otherwise, please run "ls -la .ssh" on the server and [edit] your question to add the output.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in `/var/log/auth.log` which stated:
`Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory <home directory>`

What I had done is moved the git user's home directory to a new location, and this folder had different than standard permissions and ownership than home directories do by default. I assume this was the problem. Moving the home directory back to what it was fixed the issue. Thank you to Kenster for their comment. I did not think to look for logs on the server side.